# add html tags around naked text inside an element using php

Tags: php, html, tags

I have the following html string example. I want to add tags around the naked text:

```
$html='<span>text1</span>  text2   <a href="yahoo.com">yeahoo</a>   text4   <div>abc</div>  xyz';
```

assuming correctly formatted html I would like to add a tag (E.g. ) around text2, text4 and xyz.

I envision a simple function that is called: `$resHtml=addTagsToNakedText($html,'<span>','</span>');`

The net result should be:

```
'<span>text1</span><span>  text2   </span><a href="yahoo.com">yeahoo</a><span>   text4   </span><div>abc</div><span>  xyz</span>'
```

Any ideas how to do this? I assume this needs some regular expression capabilities.

Thanks

Comment: Obligatory answer link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: That link was mostly in jest; it's the canonical "using Regex to parse HTML" answer :). But there is a lot of truth to it. You're better off using a real parser.

Comment: I already figured out how to use the DOM to do what i need using SImple HTML Dom http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/index.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit goes to:

Obligatory answer link: stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/… – SimpleCoder yesterday

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to parse the string into a HTML fragment that can be manipulated with DOM functions. How to do this is an exercise left to the reader.

An alternative hack is to write a simple parser that performs tag-balancing and knows when to wrap text. Again, this is an exercise for the reader.

Comment: I know parsing is my best bet. I was hoping for some genius here who can direct me to some clever regular expression to do this. I thought maybe tidy could do it but could not see an option.

Answer (score 0):

An other fun exercise would be to parse every single character in the file, unsing a counter.

- When matching a '<' the counter goes +1;
- When matching a '/' then a '>', the counter goes -1
- When matching a '<' then a '/', the counter goes -1. If the counter is at 0, then it waits for the next '>' and add the second parameter of addTagsToNakedTex. As soon as it gets to 1, then you add one char earlier the third parameter of addTagsToNakedTex.

But it means that you have a defined coding style, like whithout spaces between '<' and '/' for closing tags.

Answer (score 0):

```
function tags($tag_open, $text, $tag_close) {<br />
   return $tag_open.$text.$tag_close;<br />
}
$output_string = tags('< span >', 'Enter some text in here..', '< / span >');
```